# How to use Intent.ACTION_PICK with response, but withou Activity?

Tags: java, android, ane

I have in onCreate Activity classs this code, but I do not want to use Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Exist some solution for capture event/response after image pick without activity?

Comment: towards addressing my problem helped this page https://forums.adobe.com/message/6280632?tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exist some solution for capture event/response after image pick without activity?

No, sorry. `startActivityForResult()` is only available from an `Activity`.